# How can I run helm tests in parallel?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have several helm test templates. Since they are long to run, I need to run them in parallel.

I read in the documentation the option `--parallel --max <nb>` exists in helm v2, but it seems to be removed in helm v3.

Is there an alternative?